# How should I store a PEM file?

Tags: c#, cookies, pem

My website needs to retrieve a digitally signed cookie and verify it using an X509Certifictate2 generated from the certificate section contained inside a PEM file - e.g.

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
largequantityofgobbledygook
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

My first thought was to store the PEM file as a file on the webserver, but it occurs to me that I could just as easily store it as a manifest constant in the class that needs it

```
private const string PEM = @"
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
largequantityofgobbledygook
-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
```

Is this a correct and safe approach?

Comment: Store as a file and refer in the code as `   X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath);`

Comment: I would not save any production security critical data in the source code, because it means it will end up in your VCS. And that means everyone who had, have and will have access to your VCS will have access to your production security secrets. These kind of data should be in files only present on the server and a small number of offline backup locations.

Comment: Thank you - I will adopt this approach.